# not able to solve markup problem

Tags: html, markup, validation, w3c-validation

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fratingscorner.com%2Fproduct_rating.php%3Falias%3DPeoples-Education-Society-Institute-of-Technology-%28PESIT%29-100-feet-Ring-Road-Bangalore%26product%3DColleges&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=1&No200=1&verbose=1&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.767

**have fixed most of the errors . but could not fix the » problems ...if any1 can help it will be helpful for me.**

Comment: the markup check already tells you where the problems are.

Comment: okay, I didn't know that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W3C Validator has some more or less serious flaws. On your page, it detect `&raquo;` as an ending `>` ... which it isn't. I suggest you download [Total Validator](http://www.totalvalidator.com/tool/index.html), which is a way more standard compliant validator. You'll see a great difference.

Comment: No problem. I hope Total Validator will be of great use to you.

Comment: @Gert G - but i have same &raquo; in some other page . there its treated well. dono if its code fault ..

Comment: @Gert G - i did a validation using the tool you suggested . more errors are like
 The default style sheet language must be specified when style attributes are used:    for inline styles. how do i solve this.

Comment: The &raquo;'s should be fine. They're HTML escape codes.

Comment: The beauty with Total Validator is that at the end of the page it gives a hint of how to fix the errors reported for the different error codes. In your case, just add <META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"> in the HEAD section of your page and the 63 E650 errors will disappear.

Comment: As an added bonus, Total Validator can check your links. Just click in "Check for broken links".